# How to count rows on joined table without WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, case

I have two related tables **users** and **networks** — social-media accounts of corresponding user. Accounts (networks) could be like these: facebook, linkedin, youtube, vimeo, etc...

Every user could have zero or more social-media accounts (in **networks** table).

In my case I need to count **only video** accounts (youtube and/or vimeo) of each user.

I'm trying this two queries:

```
SELECT users.email, COUNT(networks.network) as video_networks_counter,
FROM users
LEFT JOIN networks ON networks.user_id = users.id
WHERE networks.network='youtube' OR networks.network='video'
GROUP BY users.id
```

and

```
SELECT users.email, 
CASE networks.network WHEN 'youtube' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as video_networks_counter,
CASE networks.network WHEN 'vimeo' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as video_networks_counter
FROM users
LEFT JOIN networks ON networks.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY users.id
```

Which don't work as desired.

Problem with first query is that user could not have any networks but he also have to be in a list with 0 counter. So `WHERE` condition seems to be useless in my case.

Second query with `CASE` also doesn't work.

Comment: Equality condition on `WHERE` clause that refers to second table with `LEFT OUTER JOIN` makes it literally a `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. A WHERE or INNER JOIN ON that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL after an OUTER JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings, names & line numbers & with & without 'site:stackoverflow.com' and read many hits & answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as tabular initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS "doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything.  Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Please ask one question per post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the conditions to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT u.email, COUNT(n.network) as video_networks_counter
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     networks n
     ON n.user_id = u.id AND
        n.network IN ('youtube', 'video')
GROUP BY u.email;
```

Notes:

- Your `WHERE` clause turns the outer join into an inner join, because `NULL` values do not match.
- `IN` is simpler than `OR` clauses for this type of comparison.
- The `GROUP BY` key should match the unaggregated columns in the `SELECT`.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- You may intend `'vimeo'` rather than `'video'`.

And, if you want to count them separately:

```
SELECT u.email, COUNT(n.network) as video_networks_counter,
       SUM( n.network = 'youtube') as num_youtube,
       SUM( n.network = 'vimeo') as num_vimeo           
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     networks n
     ON n.user_id = u.id AND
        n.network IN ('youtube', 'vimeo')
GROUP BY u.email;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your 1st query set the conditions in the ON clause and remove WHERE:

```
SELECT users.email, COUNT(networks.network) as video_networks_counter,
FROM users
LEFT JOIN networks ON networks.user_id = users.id
AND (networks.network='youtube' OR networks.network='video')
GROUP BY users.id
```

Your WHERE clause removes all the users that do not have an account making the LEFT JOIN useless.

Answer (score 0):

You could just sum up how often your condition is true

```
SELECT u.email, 
       SUM(n.network IN ('youtube', 'video')) as video_networks_counter,
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN networks n ON n.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.email
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this option with CASE and SUM-

```
SELECT users.email, 
SUM(
    CASE 
        WHEN networks.network='youtube' OR networks.network='video' THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END
) as video_networks_counter,
FROM users
LEFT JOIN networks ON networks.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY users.email
```